# Every couple of hours, my node desyncs

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, lighthouse

For some reason, every couple of hours when I check on my node, my Geth log files show '`Imported new potential chain segment`,' and then once synced, it goes back to normal for a couple of hours.

The issue is when running `eth.syncing` in my Geth console, it shows `false`, but when running `eth.blockNumber` to check the current block, it shows a block somewhere in the range of 1 hour to 9 hours behind. I'm not sure what this is caused by, whether it's a time zone error or something else, but it occurs once every 24 hours, and I can't pinpoint the time it occurs.

Not sure if this could be much help, but my Lighthouse logs show this:

`INFO Ready for Deneb` `info: ensure the execution endpoint is updated to the latest Deneb/Cancun release, service: slot_notifier`

And also shows the following whenever the blocks are out of sync:

`WARN Error whilst processing payload status  error: Api { error: HttpClient(url: http://localhost:8551/, kind: timeout, detail: operation timed out) }, service: exec`

Once the node syncs back, it is absolutely fine for ages until it stops again.